# How to sort by dynamically with ascending or descending in Marklogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10

```
let $sortelement := 'Salary' 
let $sortby := 'ascending'
for $doc in collection('employee')
order by $doc/*[local-name() eq $sortelement] $sortby
return $doc
```

This code throws and error, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Sadly, there's no convenient way of doing this in standard XQuery. It requires a workaround such as repeating the whole logic inside a conditional `if ($sortby='ascending') then ... else ...; or calling reverse() on the result. Even `fn:sort()` doesn't help. There might be a MarkLogic-specific solution, however.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to build the `order by` dynamically within a FLWOR statement, you can't. As Michael Kay points out in the comments, you could use a conditional statement and decide whether or not to [`reverse()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-semantics/#sec_fn_reverse) the `ascending` (default) sorted sequence.

```
let $sortelement := 'Salary' 
let $sortby := 'ascending'
let $results :=
  for $doc in collection('employee')
  order by $doc/*[local-name() eq $sortelement] 
  return $doc
return
  if ($sortby eq 'descending')
  then reverse($results)
  else $results
```

Depending upon how many documents are in your collection, retrieving every document and sorting them won't scale. It can take a long time, and can exceed memory limits for expanded tree cache.

If you have indexes on those elements, then you can dynamically build a [`cts:index-order()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:index-order) and specify as the third parameter for `cts:search()` in order to get them returned in the specified order:

```
let $sortelement := 'Salary'
let $sortby := 'ascending'
return 
  cts:search(doc(), 
    cts:collection-query("employee"),  
    cts:index-order(cts:element-reference(xs:QName($sortelement)), $sortby)
  )
```